# manage images profile with mysql?

Tags: php, android, mysql, image, social-networking

I'm implementing profile pictures in my android application. I came to a decision that I don't know which road to take. The problem is that I have to store the images that users upload and view them also to their contacts / friends, as in telegram I see the images of others and they see mine.
1) First hypothesis:
I know that MySQL can store images in a field with the "blob" (tell me if I'm wrong), so you just have to upload and download images from grabbing this field.
2) Second hypothesis:
The user loads the image, I memorize in a folder (a bit 'like a cloud), unless its path on the server in a field in the database (for example in the field photo I put "http:site/project/image.jpg ") and I download the photos to his friends in this way.

I do not know how to do, which one should I choose? The first method (to store the file directly in mysql) does not make me become the database slower and less accurate?
The application handles messages, post etc. (as in a social network), the pictures can give problems ??
The second method seems faster though less elegant. I trust in your wise advice, thanks for the reply: D

Comment: use files. everybody else do like that (G+, EyeEm, etc) and there's a good reason for it.

Answer (score -1):

IMHO - store images as files and store only their paths to database.